# Restrict access for admin part and user's management

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I'm using `CanCan`. There is a user registration page and an admin namespace where an admin manages the users. There is 2 abilities: "`normal`" and "`admin_ability`" for admin part of the web site:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users
  end
```

How do I restrict access so that:

- anyone can create an user by registration
- an user can edit themself and delete
- and an admin can any user and delete

I tried to do that but didn't found how to do exactly what I wanted. Your thoughts?

Comment: Simple check out https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki - there are a few really helpful articles and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the permissions in your abilities model, placed in app/models.

For instance, in app/model/admin_ability.rb:

```
class AdminAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(admin)
    if admin
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your app/models/user_ability.rb (I guess that this is what you mean with "normal"):

```
class UserAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user
     user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
        can :manage, User, :id => user.id
    end
end
```

You can restrict the actions allowed to a certain role; :manage is all, but you can use :read, :show, :edit, :destroy or an array with some of them.

You can find deeper information here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities